# Finding a closed form of $f(n) = \frac{n-4}{n}f(n-1)+1\ ,\ n \geq 5$ where $f(4) = 1$.

Tags: recurrence-relations, functional-equations

I'm trying to find the closed form of

$f(n) = \frac{n-4}{n}f(n-1)+1\ ,\ n \geq 5$ where $f(4) = 1$.

Empirically, it turns out the answer is simply $f(n)=1+\frac{n-4}{5}\ ,\ n \geq 4$, but I'm having a hard time getting there. I've tried two ways but neither is very successful. Could someone please suggest a way through?

**Attempt 1:** I try to set up a generating function

$$G(x)=f(4)x^4+f(5)x^5+\dots=\sum_{k=4}^\infty f(k)x^k$$

Substituting in the recurrence (edit: noticed I forgot to add the +1)
$$\begin{align}G(x)&=x^4+\sum_{k=5}^\infty(1-\frac{4}{k})f(k-1)x^k \\
&=x^4+x\sum_{k=5}^\infty (1-\frac{4}{k}) f(k-1)x^{k-1} \\
&= x^4+x\sum_{k=4}^\infty (1-\frac{4}{k+1})f(k)x^k  \\
&= x^4+xG(x)-x\sum_{k=4}^\infty \frac{4}{k+1}f(k)x^k
\end{align} $$

But I don't know how to express the last part in terms of G(x).

**Attempt 2:** Just brute force it:

With arbitrary $k$,

$$\begin{align}f(n) &= \frac{(n-4)(n-5) \dots (n-(k+3))}{n(n-1)\dots(n-(k-1))}f(n-k)\\
&\ \ + \left(1+\frac{n-4}{n}+\frac{(n-4)(n-5)}{n(n-1)}+\dots+\frac{(n-4)\dots(n-(k+2))}{n\dots(n-(k-2))}\right)\end{align}$$
Setting $n-k=4 \implies k = n -4$ and using $f(4)=1$,

$$\begin{align} f(n) &= \frac{(n-4)!}{n!/4!}+\left(1+\frac{n-4}{n}+\frac{(n-4)(n-5)}{n(n-1)}+\dots+\frac{(n-4)\dots2}{n \dots 6}\right) \\
&= {n \choose 4}^{-1}+\left(1+\frac{(n-4)!}{n!}\left(\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-5)!} + \frac{(n-2)!}{(n-6)!}+\dots +\frac{5!}{1!}\right)\right) 
 \\
&= {n \choose 4}^{-1}+\frac{(n-4)!}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^{n-5}\frac{(k+4)!}{k!} \\
&= {n \choose 4}^{-1}+\frac{1}{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}\sum_{k=1}^{n-5}(k+4)(k+3)(k+2)(k+1) \\
&= {n \choose 4}^{-1}+\frac{1}{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}\sum_{k=5}^{n-1}k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)\end{align}$$

Empirically this seems to be correct, but even Mathematica refuses to simplify it all the way down. Surely there is a better way?

Comment: I suppose that there is a mistake somewhere

Comment: @Paradox FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(n)%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7Bn-4%7D%7Bn%7Df(n-1)%2B1%24&p=1), I found the similar question [Using generating functions to solve a recurrence](/q/1879395/602049), but it deals with the somewhat different recurrence relation $f(n) = \frac{n-1}{n}f(n-1) + 1$ instead.

Comment: After you set $n-k=4$, write the first term as $\frac{4! (n-4)!}{n!}$ and write the 1 inside the brackets as $\frac{(n-4)!}{(n-4)!}$. Then factorise the $(n-4)!$ an go from there.

Comment: 1. You can always try induction. 2. Checking several first values shows, that $f(n)$ is linear at least for several first $n$. $f(n)-f(n-1)=1-\frac{4}{n}f(n-1)$. For $f(n)-f(n-1)$ to be constant one needs $f(n-1)=kn$ with $f(n)-f(n-1)=1-4k=k$, $k=\frac{1}{5}$. Initial condition satisfies $f(4)=k\cdot 5$, that's why solution is linear.

Comment: True, I always underrate using induction on these problems. I need to use it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the recursive definition, we have the identity

$$\sum_{n=5}^\infty f(n) x^n = \sum_{n=5}^\infty \frac{n-4}n f(n-1) x^n + \sum_{n=5}^\infty x^n$$

With $G(x) = \sum\limits_{n=4}^\infty f(n)x^n$, for $|x|<1$ we have

$$\begin{align*}
G(x) - x^4 &= \sum_{n=5}^\infty f(n-1) x^n - 4 \sum_{n=5}^\infty \frac{f(n-1)}n x^n + \left(\frac1{1-x} - 1 - x - x^2 - x^3 - x^4\right) \\[1ex]
G(x) &= x \sum_{n=5}^\infty f(n-1) x^{n-1} - 4 \sum_{n=5}^\infty \frac{f(n-1)}n x^n + \frac{x^4}{1-x} \\[1ex]
G(x) &= x G(x) - 4 \sum_{n=5}^\infty \frac{f(n-1)}n x^n + \frac{x^4}{1-x} \\[1ex]
(1-x) G(x) &= -4 \phi(x) + \frac{x^4}{1-x}
\end{align*}$$

where $\phi'(x) = G(x)$. Differentiating both sides and isolating $G'(x)$ yields the linear differential equation

$$G'(x) + \frac3{1-x}G(x) = \frac{4x^3-3x^4}{(1-x)^3}$$

which is solved below using the integrating factor method.

$$\begin{align*}
\frac1{(1-x)^3} G'(x) + \frac3{(1-x)^4}G(x) &= \frac{4x^3-3x^4}{(1-x)^6} \\[1ex]
\left(\frac1{(1-x)^3} G(x)\right)' &= \frac{4x^3-3x^4}{(1-x)^6} \\[1ex]
G(x) &= (1-x)^3 \int_0^x \frac{4\xi^3-3\xi^4}{(1-\xi)^6} \, d\xi \\[1ex]
G(x) &= \frac{x^4 (5-4x)}{5 (1-x)^2}
\end{align*}$$

Next, get the power series expansion of $G(x)$ to determine $f(n)$. Polynomial division yields

$$G(x) = -\frac{4x^3}5 - \frac{3x^2}5 - \frac{2x}5 - \frac15 + \frac15 \frac1{(1-x)^2}$$

Use the series for the derivative of $\frac1{1-x}$ to wrap up.

$$\frac1{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \implies \frac1{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}$$

Hence

$$G(x) = -\frac{4x^3}5 - \frac{3x^2}5 - \frac{2x}5 - \frac15 + \frac15 \left(1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + \sum_{n=5}^\infty nx^{n-1}\right) \\ G(x) = \frac15 \sum_{n=4}^\infty (n+1)x^n = \sum_{n=4}^\infty f(n)x^n$$
$$\implies f(n) = \frac{n+1}5$$

Comment: Nice! It didn't occur to me to set it up with a function $\phi(x)$ such that $\phi'(x)=G(x)$. This is certainly the hardest solution using a generating function I've seen, but it seems to work. (At least, with a 5 in the final denominator)

Comment: That was a cascading typo. Fixed

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

If you solve
$$f(n) = \frac{n-4}{n}f(n-1)+1$$ the solution is given by
$$f(n)=\frac {n+1} 5+\frac C{(n-3) (n-2) (n-1) n}$$ Then, ..., try to find the mistake.

Comment: +) It says that $f(4)=1$, so it's easy to find $C=0$, $f(n)=\dfrac{n+1}{5}.$

Comment: Is that an ansatz? How did you come up with it.

Answer (score 1):

Alt. hint: write it as $\lambda_nf(n) = \lambda_{n-1}f(n-1) + \mu_n$ where $\lambda_n=\mu_n=n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] After telescoping $\,\lambda_nf(n) = \lambda_4 f(4) + \sum_{k=5}^n \mu_k\,$ where $\,\lambda_4 = 24\,$, $\,f(4)=1\,$, and the sum of falling factorials can be calculated as shown at [$\sum r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)$ is equal to?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2346488/sum-rr1r2r3-is-equal-to), or in the general case [Partial sums of falling factorials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1304792/partial-sums-of-falling-factorials).

Answer (score 1):

This recurrence is linear so we can solve it as follows

$$
\cases{
f_n = f_n^h+f_n^p\\
f_n^h = \frac{n-4}{n}f_{n-1}^h\\
f_n^p = \frac{n-4}{n}f_{n-1}^p + 1\\
}
$$

The solution for the homogeneous part is easy to determine

$$
f_n^h = \frac{c_0}{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}
$$

now assuming $f_n^p = \frac{c_0(n)}{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}$ after substitution we have

$$
c_0(n)-c_0(n-1) = n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)
$$

and solving

$$
c_0(n) = \frac 15(n+1)n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)
$$

hence

$$
f_n^p = \frac 15(n+1)
$$

and

$$f_n = \frac{f_0}{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)} + \frac 15(n+1)$$

Comment: Thanks! In general can you always assume $f_n^p$ will have same form as $f_n^h$, or was this just an educated guess?

Comment: For linear recurrences this is the equivalent to the variation of constants in differential equations. In this case we can propose always a particular which is the homogeneous with a variable constant as in the solved case.